Rust workspace with circular dependency when only want to have single output
Is it possible to have a circular dependency in rust workspaces when crates are not usable by themselves?
the problem with circular dependencies is that you can't build one as it needs the other
but I don't care to have a single target that is built all at once like it was a single project
Why use workspaces in the first place?
Let's say I have this structure:
- crates:
  - storage:
    - hash_table
    - b_tree
    - buffer_pool
  - catalog

Visibility:
I want to mark some function visibility to be inside that crate (e.g. only inside b_tree) I need to do pub(in crate::storage:b_tree) everywhere (having 2 layers is ok but what about 4?)
Imports:
I want to use some function from other "crate" it will require me to have the full structure crate::storage::b_tree or have to propagate the use up the tree

you can use crate::storage::b_tree then pub(in b_tree).

Yes but I still need to have the entire path in the use

Well yes, but it's a one time cost for each module and it's unavoidable.

It's not clear to me how the burden of specifying a full path (add a re-export?) has to do with circular dependencies

If I don't use workspaces I'll have to deal with those which is the reason I choose workspaces
